# How does the jqueryUI autocomplete example get away with not using $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am determined to figure out how the example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default works without being wrapped in a $(document).ready because I just spend over an hour and a half trying unsuccessfully to reproduce this when all I needed to do was wrap it in the $(document).ready

At the very bottom of the source I see this one, but nothing to do with the autocomplete.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').click(function(){
    this.blur();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `$(function () {blah})` is the same as using $(document).ready. It's the third syntax in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).